# What is the appropriate airfoil config for Raked Wingtips?

Tags: wing, winglets, high-lift-device

I'm doing a research about wingtip devices and while I'm searching about raked wingtip, I've wondered what is the best airfoil configuration for it?

Should it be the same as the whole wing?

My study is for application on aerodesign models that should have a low weight and carry a lot of weight.